# how to pass command line argument in Mac Application

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, command-line-arguments

I have created a Command line tool application ( Xocde --> New App --> Command line tool) and its running without any problem, 
Now i want to run it through terminal and pass some command line argument, something like this

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    std::cout << "got "<<argc<<" arguments";

    for ( int i = 0; i<argc;i++){
        std::cout << "argument:"<<i<<"= "<<argv[i];
    }

//// some other piece of code 
}
```

if i type on the terminal

```
>open VisiMacXsltConverter --args fdafsdfasf i am getting output 

got 1 argumentsargument:0= /Applications/VisiMacXsltConverte
```

I want to know through command line what is the way to pass the argument

Comment: Possibly needs migration to Superuser, and is a duplicate of this:

http://superuser.com/questions/16750/how-can-i-run-an-application-with-command-line-arguments-in-mac-os

Comment: @KingCronus i tried following:> AppName -P fdsfa fdsa but same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you want to run it with *open*?

I would run it with (if you have it in you $PATH you should omit the './'):

```
./VisiMacXsltConverter arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4
```

Hope I have not misunderstood you question.

Answer (score 3):

If you use just one - (hyphen) those values will go into a volatile UserDefaults dictionary (will also override other keys for the life of the process).

`./program -Param 4`

```objectivec
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {
        NSLog(@"param = %@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"Param"]);        
    }
    return 0;
}
```

or you can just pass these in how ever you want and use the following which will give you an NSArray of NSStrings.

```objectivec
[[NSProcessInfo processInfo] arguments];
```